# Grouping by an alias

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

```
SELECT COALESCE (rsu.last_name + ', ' + rsu.first_name + ' ' + rsu.middle_name + '.', rsu.last_name + ', ' + rsu.first_name)  as student_name, rsu.day_id
FROM roster_school_unattended rsu
GROUP BY student_name
ORDER BY rsu.day_id
```

does not work. What's the most elegant workaround?

EDIT: The result-set should have something like this

```
Muster, Hans | 2011-11-01
Muster, Hans | 2011-11-02
Williams, Clay | 2011-10-01
Williams, Clay | 2011-10-02
```

First the name is grouped by, then for each name there is a sorting of dates.

Comment: You need to stop thinking in terms of "elegant" when you query a database. Often the least elegant looking code is the best from the database perspective of performance which is far more critical than "elegance".  You can never go wrong writing database code from a performance perspective (what is most likely to perform best) first. Once you get used to what is the best performing type of SQL for your database, it is just as easy to maintain as "elegant" code.

Comment: If you intend to frequently group the names together that way, I find it best to make that a persisted calculated column.  That way you don't have to do all that nasty coalesce and concatenation stuff more than once.

Comment: Additionally, your edit shows that you don't need GROUP BY.  You mean that you want everything ordered by the name column, and then the date column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** Whole thing replaced as the recent edit to the question shows that GROUP BY isn't needed...

Without any changes for 'elegance'...

```
SELECT
  rsu.last_name + ', ' + rsu.first_name + COALESCE (' ' + rsu.middle_name + '.', '') as student_name,
  rsu.day_id
FROM
  roster_school_unattended  AS [rsu]
ORDER BY
  rsu.last_name + ', ' + rsu.first_name + COALESCE (' ' + rsu.middle_name + '.', ''),
  rsu.day_id
```

Possible change for 'elegance'...

```
WITH formatted_rsu AS
(
  SELECT rsu.last_name + ', ' + rsu.first_name + COALESCE (' ' + rsu.middle_name + '.', '') as student_name, rsu.day_id
  FROM   roster_school_unattended  AS [rsu]
)
SELECT   student_name, day_id
FROM     formatted_rus
ORDER BY student_name, day_id
```

Another possible using APPLY...

```
SELECT      formatted_rsu.student_name, rsu.day_id
FROM        roster_school_unattended  AS [rsu]
CROSS APPLY (SELECT rsu.last_name + ', ' + rsu.first_name + COALESCE (' ' + rsu.middle_name + '.', '') as student_name) AS [formatted_rsu]
ORDER BY    formatted_rsu.student_name, rsu.day_id
```

Answer (score 2):

Doing a subselect would let you avoid having to type it twice:

```
select t.student_name, t.day_id
from (
  select COALESCE (rsu.last_name + ', ' + rsu.first_name + ' ' + rsu.middle_name + '.', rsu.last_name + ', ' + rsu.first_name) as student_name, 
    rsu.day_id
  from roster_school_unattended rsu ) t
group by t.student_name
order by t.day_id
```

But you've still got a problem with the day_id - it's not included in your grouping clause, so you won't be able to select it without using an aggregate (such as MAX).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery:

```
select student_name, day_id
from (SELECT COALESCE (rsu.last_name + ', ' + rsu.first_name + ' ' + rsu.middle_name + '.', rsu.last_name + ', ' + rsu.first_name)  as student_name, rsu.day_id
FROM roster_school_unattended rsu
) as rows
GROUP BY student_name
ORDER BY day_id
```

Answer (score 0):

`CROSS APPLY` is your friend for aliasing non-windowed expressions:

```
SELECT this.student_name, MAX(rsu.day_id) AS day_id
FROM roster_school_unattended rsu
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT COALESCE (
      rsu.last_name+', '+rsu.first_name+' '+rsu.middle_name+'.'
    , rsu.last_name+', '+rsu.first_name
    )  AS student_name
  ) this
GROUP BY this.student_name
ORDER BY this.student_name, MAX(rsu.day_id)
```

(assumes SQL2005 and above).

Answer (score 0):

I would go with:

```
SELECT
    rsu.last_name
    + ', ' + rsu.first_name
    + COALESCE ( ' ' + rsu.middle_name + '.'
               , ''
               )
    AS student_name
  , rsu.day_id
FROM
    roster_school_unattended AS rsu
ORDER BY
    rsu.last_name
  , rsu.first_name
  , rsu.middle_name
  , rsu.day_id
```